# Django rest framework reverse relation serializers exclude fields

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two models `Question` and `Options`

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_identifier = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question_text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    question_category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    question_tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Options(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField('Question', related_name='options', blank=False, null=False)
    option1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,null=True)
    option2 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False,null=True)
    option3 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    option4 = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
```

I have written a serializer for Question model which serializes options as well (reverse relation). I want to omit the question field from the Options? Is there a way to achieve this?

My Question Serializer:-

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for Question object from qna.models
    """
    question_category = CategorySerializer(many=True,write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'options', 'question_identifier','question_text','question_tags','question_category')
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating a separate serializer for an `Options` model.And use it instead of default field, without `depth` value.

```
class OptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Options
        fields = ('option1', 'option2', 'option3')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_category = CategorySerializer(many=True,write_only=True)
    options = OptionsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'options', 'question_identifier','question_text','question_tags','question_category')
```